# can not use HTTP GET inside a asp.net web service [WebMethod]

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I have a problem using HTTP GET/POST via HttpWebRequest in .Net when that is inside a asp.net web service
Could some one help what could be the issue here.
The same piece of code works fine from a Windows Form/ Console Application

```
    [WebMethod]
    public string someWebMethod()
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
        WebResponse resp = request.GetResponse(); <---------This is hanging... any idea how to work around?
         .......

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I made it work, by specifying my default proxy explicitly.

```
[WebMethod]
     public string someWebMethod()
     {
           HttpWebRequest request =(HttpWebRequest) HttpWebRequest.Create(@"http://www.google.com");
           request.Proxy = new WebProxy("10.168.0.17", 8080);
      }
```